# HAProxy SSL Pass Through with two backends having individual hostnames

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I am trying to setup HAProxy server for SSL Pass Through.

Requirement is, I will be getting requests e.g. api.mydomain.com, web.mydomain.com, in HAProxy I would like to receive the requests and based on their host name forward to their relevant backend.

Using the below configuration, my HA Proxy starts and when I visit web.mydomain.com, I expect to send to web.mydomain.com, it is sent to api.mydomain.com.

Following is my configuration:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
    local2.*    /var/log/haproxy.log
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
    mode                    tcp
    log                     global
    option                  tcplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

frontend localhost
    bind *:443
    option tcplog
    mode tcp
    default_backend api_nodes
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }

    acl ACL_api_mydomain.comhdr(host) -i api.mydomain.com
    use_backend api_nodes if ACL_api_mydomain.com

    acl ACL_web_mydomain.comhdr(host) -i web.mydomain.com
    use_backend web_nodes if ACL_web_mydomain.com

backend api_nodes
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option tcp-check
    server web01 192.0.0.68:5002/healthcheck check

backend web_nodes
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option tcp-check
    server web01 192.0.0.68:5001 check
```

I am using HAProxy 1.5.x version.

Comment: You're trying to read headers of an encrypted stream which won't work, and HAProxy 1.5 is EOL

Comment: I upgraded it to 2.3.9 and added these lines but still it works the same way:

<config>
    acl acl_api ssl_fc_sni api.mydomain.com
    acl acl_web ssl_fc_sni web.mydomain.com
    use_backend api_nodes if acl_api
    use_backend web_nodes if acl_web
</config>

Comment: Hmm that's more likely to work... Are you sure clients are sending an SNI?

Comment: They are sending SNIs. There are two issues. One I want to have an SSL Pass Through (which means I don't want the HAProxy to make any changes to the original request and pass it as it is to upstream). To know about the ssl_fc_sni, I need to provide the certificate to frontend, unfortunately I have separate certs for both domains. I don't know if there is a way to provide two certs for "bind *:443 ssl crt /opt/mydomain/ssl/certs/api.mydomain.com.pem ciphers ...."

An easy here might be to have two LBs setup and do what I want to achieve.

Comment: You can pass a crt-list to HAProxy to provide a certificate per SNI, however TCP mode inspection of SNI should work, I actually use it on some servers... I'll have a look when I get to work after the weekend.

Comment: If we can provide a crt-list and HAProxy supports, it would be good. For our test run, I will now setup it on two small LB instances. Thank you for the input. See if you share some info on how you use it.